# Daily builds for elementary OS?

Tags: updates

Is there any way to get daily/beta builds of elementary OS installed? I think there is a daily ppa or something, but is that still even maintained? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a daily PPA, and it looks like many of the packages have been updated within the last month:

https://launchpad.net/~elementary-os/+archive/ubuntu/daily